# How do we fit previous models' data into the last model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

How do we fit previous models' data into the last model?
The last `fit` in this code isn't working.
I am trying to build a fairly complicated model, about 40 models. How do I `fit` data only to the last model that feeds to all previous models?
I start with `a_in` `b_in` processed together, and add another single input `s_in` to create final output of 3; to be matched with `c_out`. I need to produce 40 something instances like this, and keep them chaining them.

```
#Input
a_in=np.array([[3,4,5],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[4,6,8]])
b_in=np.array([[9,5,3],[1,0,2],[7,3,1],[6,6,6]])
s_in = np.array([[5],[7],[9],[0]])

#Output
c_out = np.array([[6,2,3],[0,2,7],[9,6,1],[8,6,5]])

a = keras.Input(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.float64)
aModel = keras.layers.Flatten()(a)

b = keras.Input(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.float64)
bModel = keras.layers.Flatten()(b)

s = keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float64)

aModel = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(a)
aModel = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(aModel)
aModel = keras.Model(inputs=a, outputs=aModel, name="a")

bModel = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(b)
bModel = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(bModel)
bModel = keras.Model(inputs=b, outputs=bModel, name="b")

combine = keras.layers.concatenate([aModel.output, bModel.output, s], dtype=tf.float64) #inject s in the middle stage

cModel = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(combine)
cModel = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(cModel)
cModel = keras.Model(inputs=combine, outputs=cModel, name="c")

cModel.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics='accuracy')

aModel.summary()
bModel.summary()
cModel.summary()

keras.utils.plot_model(cModel, "baby-architecture.png", show_shapes=True)


cModel.fit([a_in, b_in, s_in],[c_out],epochs=1, shuffle=False, verbose=1)
```

Summary:

```
Model: "a"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 3)]               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 10)                40        
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 11        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 51 (204.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 51 (204.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "b"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 3)]               0         
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 10)                40        
                                                                 
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 11        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 51 (204.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 51 (204.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "c"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_4 (InputLayer)        [(None, 3)]               0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 10)                40        
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 33        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 73 (292.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 73 (292.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

[image]

Error:

```
ValueError: Layer "c" expects 1 input(s), but it received 3 input tensors. 
    Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 3) dtype=int64>, 
    <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 3) dtype=int64>, 
<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, 1) dtype=int64>]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data you are trying to fit ? And the error that you are getting. What's `a_in` and `b_in` ? Would be good if you refer [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @rr_goyal Modified Q with many details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, `cModel` is the main model that combines the outputs from `bModel` and `aModel`, it also has its own input `s_in`. So, when you are fitting data into `cModel`, the input layer of `cModel` will be used to take inputs which will be passed further. If you review `cModel's` input layer, it expects the output of models `aModel` and `bModel` but in your fit function, you are passing the inputs of `aModel`, `bModel` and `s_in`. Based on this, I have modified your code a little bit which now looks like -

```
#Input
a_in=np.array([[3,4,5],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[4,6,8]])
b_in=np.array([[9,5,3],[1,0,2],[7,3,1],[6,6,6]])
s_in = np.array([[5],[7],[9],[0]])

#Output
c_out = np.array([[6,2,3],[0,2,7],[9,6,1],[8,6,5]])

a = keras.Input(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.float64, name="a")
b = keras.Input(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.float64, name="b")
s = keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float64, name="s")

aModel = keras.layers.Flatten()(a)
aModel = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(aModel)
aModel = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(aModel)
aModel = keras.Model(inputs=a, outputs=aModel)

bModel = keras.layers.Flatten()(b)
bModel = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(bModel)
bModel = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(bModel)
bModel = keras.Model(inputs=b, outputs=bModel, name="b")


cModel = keras.layers.Concatenate()([aModel.output, bModel.output, s])
cModel = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')(cModel)
cModel = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(cModel)

# CHANGES HERE: the inputs to the model.
cModel = keras.Model(inputs=[a,b,s], outputs=cModel, name="c")

cModel.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics='accuracy')

# aModel.summary()
# bModel.summary()
cModel.summary()

keras.utils.plot_model(cModel, "baby-architecture.png", show_shapes=True)

# CHANGES HERE: Your c_out is a numpy ndarry, which does not require any other typecasting.
cModel.fit({"a": a_in, "b": b_in, "s": s_in}, c_out, epochs=1, shuffle=False, verbose=1)
```

Your model now looks like this - [image: Model Architecture]

Comment: I am afraid not because the model expects 3 inputs.